# How to avoid bad user experience when adding new permissions to Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Whenever a permission error occurs on facebook, developers are forced to 1. identify that this is actually happening, 2. ask the user to re-login.

This is a terrible user experience, and I'm surprised that Facebook even allows it to exist.

Is there any way to easily add a permission to a session? If not, are there any ways to make this easier?

Comment: Its because for every user an access token in generated while logging in based on the permission given by the user to the application. whenever a permission changes a new access-token is necessary and by re-login the user finds that he is giving additional permissions to the app..

Comment: You are simply stating the problem, the problem is exactly what this question is looking for a solution to. I would appreciate if you remove your comment

Comment: I told that because, that is what Facebook does and they have certain policies/methods which they think that would be necessary for their service. And moreover that's not a bug to fix and its the way what they are doing. There is nothing we can do about that unless they change something to this..  And we dont have control over facebook!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's put it this way:

1. I authorized your app with *only* basic access (no permissions, `perms` or `scope`).
2. You automatically added the `email` permission *without* **my permission**

   1. I started receiving emails (spamming?) from you which is the worst scenario OR
   2. You have simply gained access to my email!

Facebook respects user privacy (actually it's a primary goal) and while they are trying to provide developers with the best technologies, methods and APIs to maintain the best experience there are things they can't avoid.

Each action your application want to make to the user *OR* on his behalf **must** be approved by the user and it *should be clearly stated* when the user approves it.

I've chosen the `email` permission for a purpose here, because the user *may* choose **NOT** to share his personal email with you directly (in which case Facebook will give you a proxied email). This is how far Facebook is thinking and trying to keep the user trust on them (before you!)

Just a small note, handling (*any*) API provider errors and adopting it's behavior is part of your job. And trust me, Facebook users have been installing *millions* of apps for years now and they are *used* to this behavior.

So try making your application as engaging as possible, make use of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api), Social [Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins) and [Channels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/). And you'll perform just fine.

Comment: I'm NOT saying to allow us developers to pull the rug from under the user. When we developers need to add a permission, it should be as painless as possible. Logging out and re-logging in is VERY painful to  the developer's app and thereforce it is VERY painful to facebook. It is ONLY logical that Facebook should make it easier for developers to add permissions to their apps without requiring a login

Comment: @hunterp: Who said that you need to log-out just to grant a new permission? have you checked this [example](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/does-like)? First login with the top button then check if you like the app, after that give the `user_likes` permission and like the app and check again! The JS-SDK really provide a seamless user experience.

Comment: Also please check the [OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

Comment: I'm not talking about JS API, I'm talking about Mobile apps, which use the GRAPH API